# Interacting with light DOM in a component

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component

Imagine you have a component like this [hot-form-validator](https://github.com/mercmobily/hot-form-validator):

```
<hot-form-validator>
      <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/stores/polymer">
        <paper-input required id="name" name="name" label="Your name"></paper-input>
        <paper-input required id="surname" name="surname" label="Your surname"></paper-input>
        <paper-button type="submit" raised on-click="_submit">Click!</paper-button>
      </form>
    </hot-form-validator>
```

Whatever is within the component is the light DOM.
In the component, I want to attach a listener to the `paper-button` element. What I noticed is this:

- If I add a `ready()` method to `hot-form-validator`, and find `<paper-button>`,  `<paper-button>` is not properly initialised yet.
- If I add an `attached()` method to `hot-form-validator`, and find `<paper-button>`,  `<paper-button>` is fully initialised.

I realise that the initialisation order of light DOM children is not guaranteed. However, I am a *little* confused because here the `<form>` *and* everything else in it (including `<paper-input>`, etc.) are the form's light DOM. However, `<paper-input>` and `<paper-button>` are *also* the light DOM of the form widget.

So... is `attached()` the way to go, if I want to be sure that everything is fully initialised?

Comment: What is the problem with a fully initialized child element? And, what do you wish to achieve – Polymer has several different ways to treat, trigger, register and catch events...

Comment: In my experience, yes `attached` is the way to go to be sure that everything is initialized.

Comment: Hummmm actually https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration says "This release doesn't support the domReady callback. This callback was a partial solution to the problem of determining when sibling elements and light DOM children were ready.

A more complete solution is in progress. In the meantime, if you are using domReady in 1.0 you can replace it by using the async method inside your attached callback"